# Will askers rewarding affect Stack Overflow for Teams?

Tags: support, questions, reputation, stack-overflow-for-teams

I am implementing Stack Overflow for Teams where I work and I am wondering if this change will also be rolled out for the private versions of Stack (Stack Overflow for Teams).

Personally, I do not think it is a good idea (typically it is much harder to provide a good answer than to ask a decent question) and I would like to know how this impacts Stack Overflow for Teams.

**Question:** Will askers rewarding affect Stack Overflow for Teams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the change to the reputation scoring system will affect all Stack Overflow for Teams sites. The reputation recalculation for Teams is being performed at the same time as the reputation recalculation for the public sites, and, if it is not already complete, it soon will be. You should be seeing the revised reputation counts Real Soon Now™.

The change will also be rolled out to Enterprise instances of Stack Overflow as part of the next regular maintenance release. This may take a few months, depending on release cycles.

At this time, there is no way for Teams or Enterprise users to opt out of these changes. Although you can request this of the developers, it is not likely to be implemented, given how fundamental the reputation system is to the operation of these sites.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. However, it sounds strange as I have expected that the private versions of Stack are somewhat isolated from these "experiments" (different branches, other instances of jobs recomputing stuff etc.).

Answer (score 7):

I have just checked a question I have asked on the private Stack. 1 question upvote = 10 points (instead of 5), so it has been applied.

I am still not sure that this is OK, since we are trying to provide real-life incentives based on reputation gain.

Comment: Hopefully, this will become an option for private teams, seems odd to force this through without giving such an option for situations such as the only you're describing. Can you contact SO to request it?